# Child Business Unit has No Access to All Subscribers in Triggered Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send, marketingcloudapi

I am attempting to create Triggered Sends in a Child Business Unit.

I can do so via SOAP Api just fine. The triggered send is created and configured to use the All Subscribers list.

I cannot do so via Rest Api.  The response I receive is:

```
{
"message": "MCMS_UTM_Runtime: Access to directly reference All Subscribers is disabled for account",
"errorcode": 30000,
"documentation": ""
```

}

Also, I cannot create or configure a triggered send to use the All Subscribers list within Marketing Cloud UIs, either.  It is not available for new send creature, and when I open a send created via SOAP, I receive the message: 'This triggered send uses the All Subscribers list, to which you do not have access. Saving changes may have unexpected results; please contact Marketing Cloud Support for futher information.'

[image]

Can anyone offer some insight onto which setting I need to set in my parent BU to allow for All Subscribers reference within the child BUs?  I have been unable to find any documentation on this.

Comment: are you using an token or UN/PW, it may simply be a permission issue for the user within the child BU

Comment: @EazyE For Api calls, both SOAP and Rest, I am retrieving a token with the child's account id so the creation request in both cases is using the child context. As mentioned, Soap succeeds while rest does not.  In addition, this issue is specific to this single Enterprise account that I have seen - I do not see this issue in other accounts making the same Api calls.